# What's wrong with this separation between a relative clause and the adjective?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

At about 55%-way down the page http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497:

> "Put statements in positive form," they stipulate, in a section that seeks to prevent "not" from being used as "a means of evasion."
>
> "Write with nouns and verbs, not with adjectives and adverbs," they insist. (The motivation of this mysterious decree remains unclear to me.)
>
> And then, in the very next sentence, comes a negative passive clause containing three adjectives: "The adjective hasn't been built that can pull a weak or inaccurate noun out of a tight place."
>
> That's actually not just three strikes, it's four, because in addition to contravening "positive form" and "active voice" and "nouns and verbs," **it has a relative clause ("that can pull") removed from what it belongs with (the adjective)**, which violates another edict: "Keep related words together."

1. Would the rewritten sentence in active voice be: "One hasn't built the adjective that can pull ..."
2. What's wrong with the negative form here? Musn't 1 negation be placed somewhere?
3. Would someone please explain the bolded phrase? I don't perceive anything wrong here; shouldn't the *"relative clause ("that can pull")"* be (rightly) connected with the noun? How does it make sense if it only belongs with the adjective: "that can pull a weak or inaccurate"?

Answer (score 2):

1. Probably the best way to rewrite the sentence is 'No-one has built the adjective ...'. ('One hasn't built ... *is* possible, but to my ears less natural.)
2. There is nothing wrong with negative forms. That's Prof Pullum's entire point here. Some things *are* better expressed in negative form; some things can *only* be expressed in negative form. I can't think of *any* way to express this sentence in positive form. (That said, I would advise any speaker or writer in English to express things positively *whenever possible*.)
3. The relative clause 'that can pull a weak or inaccurate noun out of a tight place' modifies 'The adjective', so the sentence (theoretically) should be 'The adjective that can pull a weak or inaccurate noun out of a tight place hasn't been built'. To my ears, this makes the subject noun phrase too long.

Comment: +1 But the *built* sentence is virtually canonical in US idiom -- "The man ain't been born that can lick him in a fair fight" -- so this is really another instance of Pullum contrasting White's sound idiomatic practice with his stuffy academic dicta.